# gnuplot max, min values from difference in columns

Tags: gnuplot, max, min

I have a tabla with 4 columns.

I need *gnuplot* to obtain the MAX and MIN values of the **difference** between columns 3 and 4 (3-4). I've tried the usual procedure but it doesn't work:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2:(\$3-\$4) with image
max=GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX
min=GPVAL_DATA_Z_MIN
```

But it **does** work if I just use for instance:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:(\$3-\$4)
max=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
min=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN
```

Meaning that the problem is with the **Z** `GPVAL` variable and the `with image` option.

I can't use my workaround because it leaves a horrible graph behind my actual graph after I use the `plot` command again to make the actual plot.

How can I work around this?

Comment: That's odd, and I'll try looking into it, but it seems like you already have a workaround.  Plot `1:($3-$4)` and get the max and min values you want, then replot using all three dimensions.  One question: why do you have the `\` character in your script?  It isn't necessary.

Comment: The problem with my workaround is that it produces a nasty plot which is not the plot I want. If I use this workaround then after I make the actual plot, that nasty plot will be seen in the back.
What character do you mean?

Comment: I meant the backslash--not sure why it didn't show up.  One trick you can use is to `set output '\dev\null'` (or some other junk file), make the first splot, then change the output to an actual file, and make your plot.  That way you won't have the first plot in the background.

Comment: I just did something very similar and it worked fine: `set origin -10,-10`. If you put this comment above as an answer, I'll mark it as the right one. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to use that trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from using the `plot` command instead of `splot`.  The `plot` command only knows about two dimensions.  If you try

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output '/dev/null'
splot 'datafile' using 1:2:($3-$4)
max=GPVAL_DATA_Z_MAX
min=GPVAL_DATA_Z_MIN
set output 'output.eps'
plot 'datafile' using 1:($3-$4) with image
```

you should be able to get the values you need.  Setting `output '\dev\null'` allows you to get those values without actually plotting the data.

Comment: I only want two dimensions actually. The `Z` value is used for a color-bar. The real command I'm using is: `plot 'datafile' using 1:2:(\$3-\$4) with image`

Comment: I've explained the issue a bit better.

Comment: Well I might have spoken too soon. I'm having some weird issues, I'll make another question as a follow-up to this one.

Comment: When I want to get the information about a dataset through a plot command, I use the `unknown` terminal.  `set term unknown` -- I think this is a little more clean than sending output to `/dev/null/` (It'll work on windows too for example).  Also note that gnuplot 4.6 has `stats` command for this purpose :  I should really download 4.6 and start playing around with it a bit ;).

Comment: Yes, `set term unknown` is more clean--I expect it would work on all OSes.  I didn't know about that option.